# Confirming that the sequence $a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}\cos{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm still trying to totally grasp the differences in proofs for sequences and series. I have a sequence $a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}\cos{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}$

In order to prove that this sequence converges, would it be correct to state that since:

$ -1 \le \cos{n} \le 1$ ,

and for $n \to \infty$ , $\sqrt{n^3}-1 \gt \sqrt{n}$

The denominator will be increasingly larger than the numerator therefore the sequence **converges**?

Comment: Yes it is right

Comment: This is good intuition as to why the limit exists and equals $0$, yes. You might want to use the so-called [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to make this rigorous.

Comment: @Sithe. A nice follow up question would be, is the series also convergent?

Comment: @imranfat What series?  And yes, good question.

Comment: @SimpleArt. It is in reference to Sithe's earlier posts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

\begin{equation}
-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}\le\frac{\sqrt{n}\cos{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}\le\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}
\end{equation}

and you use the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

To make it more correct, see that

$$0\le|a_n|=\left|\frac{\sqrt n\cos(n)}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}\right|\le\left|\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{n^3}-1}\right|=\left|\frac{n^{0.5}}{n^{1.5}-1}\right|$$

Following your logic, it should be a [basic limit concerning rational functions](http://image.slidesharecdn.com/limitefunctions-150526032702-lva1-app6892/95/limite-functionssect2224-37-638.jpg?cb=1432688800).

You could also go ahead with L'Hospital's rule and squeeze theorem to see that

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{n^{0.5}}{n^{1.5}-1}\right|\stackrel{\text{L'Hospital's}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac1{3n}\right|\to0$$